# Json.NET - JsonConvert.DeserializeObject isn't doing anything

Tags: .net, json.net, deserialization

I'm using Json.NET to deserialize a jQuery.post() JSON param.

The raw value that's posted back is in the following format

```
jobs=4-5-6-7&invoiceDate=04-05-11
```

The class I'm trying to deserialize into is

```
public class InvoiceRequest
{
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public string JobList { get; set; }
}
```

And the code I'm using for this is

```
var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
var line = sr.ReadToEnd();
var deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InvoiceRequest>(line);
```

The problem is that nothing happens when that third line is hit. When I step through the code, it reaches that line and then... nothing. The stepper disppears and the page never receives any response.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the value of `line`? If you are trying to deserialize `jobs=4-5-6-7&invoiceDate=04-05-11` - it won't work. That is not JSON format. It's a query string. JSON is something different, involving lots of quotes and curly braces~! It is usually passed as FORM/POST data, not in the URL as a query string.

Comment: ummmm thats not json, looks more like a form submission (key value pairs)

Comment: Also - If you are using WCF/REST or ASPNET/MVC2 on the server side, then you don't need to explicitly deserialize. It will be done for you, automatically. (If you're doing it right)

Comment: if your looking to post json to the server. id look here for a starter
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery

Comment: Ah, that's my embarrassing mistake. I'm using jQuery.post() with the "json" argument, thinking that this was posting in a JSON format. It turns out that this is the format of the response. Thanks for all your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because your data isn't JSON. Either change your JavaScript so that it sends data as JSON, or use [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) to parse the format it's currently in.

Answer (score 4):

The following is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, not JSON:

```
jobs=4-5-6-7&invoiceDate=04-05-11
```

If you want JSON the request should look like this:

```
{ 'jobs': '4-5-6-7', invoiceDate: '04-05-11' }
```